# To print Difference of files from different folders using powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi I using below code to compare files 2 different folders using powershell.

```
$Path1 = “D:\Path1”
$Path2 = “D:\Path2”
$OutFile = “D:\ComparisonOutputFile.txt”

If (Test-Path($OutFile)) {Remove-Item $OutFile}

“Differences in files of the same name between the following folders:” | Out-File $OutFile -append $Path1 + ” AND ” + $Path2 | Out-File $OutFile
-append
“——————————————–“ | Out-File $OutFile
-append


$Dir1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path1 -filter *.dtsconfig
$Dir2 = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path2 -filter*.dtsconfig
$FileList = Compare-Object $Dir1 $Dir2 -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent


ForEach ($File in $FileList)
{$F1 = $Path1 + “\” + $File.InputObject
$F2 = $Path2 + “\” + $File.InputObject
$File.InputObject.name | Out-File $OutFile -append
Compare-Object $(Get-Content $F1) $(Get-Content $F2) | Format-Table
-auto | Out-File $OutFile -append}
```

I am getting error while run this script,

Out-File : A Positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'D:\Path1'. At D:\A\Test.ps1: 13 char: 74

- ... folders:" | Out-File -Encoding Default $OutFile -append $Path1 + " AN...

+CategoryInfo : InvalidArugument: (:) [Out-File], parameterBindingException

- FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound, Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Help me to understand this error

Comment: Can you post the rest of the error?

Comment: You are doing strange pipes to `Out-File` one after the other.. Also, I'd recommend replacing all curly socalled 'smart-quotes' with straight ones. It's a bad habit to construct filepaths like this: `$Path1 + “\” + $File.InputObject`; use [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) for that

Comment: `$Dir2 = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path2 -filter*.dtsconfig`
There should be a space after `-filter`

Comment: @Theo mentioned smart quotes.  If you are perhaps editing your source code in MS Word, I would strongly suggest NOT doing that.  Use PowerShell ISE or even a plain text editor.